# How to Determine if (Union of Cartesian Products of Subsets) equals (Cartesian Product of Full Sets)

Tags: algorithm, set, cartesian-product

Let's say I have some finite sets: `A, B, ..., K`

I also have `A1, A2, ... An` which are subsets of A; `B1, B2, ... Bn` which are subsets of B, etc.

Let's say `S` is the cartesian product `A x B x ... x K`

and `Sn` is the cartesian product of `An x Bn x ... x Kn`

Is there an algorithm to efficiently determine if the union of all `Sn` is equivalent to `S`?

**EDIT**

I have also asked this question in the [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18684/algorithm-to-determine-if-union-of-cartesian-products-of-subsets-equals-carte) forum. An answer proves that the problem is coNP-complete. I am keeping the question open to award the bounty if the author of the answer wants to post it here.

Comment: How would you define efficiency here? Is it acceptable to examine each of the items of AxBx...xK or the product is too big?

Comment: @Michael: computing all combinations would just take too much time. In real life, the number of sets, and the number of elements in each set is practically unbound

Comment: I wrote a nice answer, but saw that a similar one has already been posted on the twin in Theoretical CS by [Andy Drucker](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/18691). I suggest that this question be closed.

Comment: @tom: yes, I have also posted the question there yesterday. I would like to keep this question open, to be able to award the bounty to Andy Drucker once (if) he posts his answer here.

Comment: @Eduardo OK. I'll post my answer in case he doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is coNP-Complete, so there is no efficient algorithm to solve it.

I will show that [3SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) can be reduced to the complement of this problem (checking if the union of all S<sub>i</sub> is not equal to S).

Consider the 3SAT problem with variables a, b, ..., k and Boolean formula

f = c<sub>1</sub> ∧ c<sub>2</sub> ∧ ... ∧ c<sub>n</sub>

where

c<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>i,1</sub> ∨ x<sub>i,2</sub> ∨ x<sub>i,3</sub>

and x<sub>i,j</sub> is a literal (either a variable or the negation of a variable).

Set A = B = C = ... = K = { true, false }.

Set A<sub>i</sub> to

- { false } if c<sub>i</sub> contains the variable a
- { true } if c<sub>i</sub> contains the negation of variable a
- { true, false } if c<sub>i</sub> does not mention a

and similarly for B<sub>i</sub> through K<sub>i</sub> for all 1 ≤ i ≤ n.

Any tuple (a, b, ..., k) ∈ S<sub>i</sub> = A<sub>i</sub> ⨯ B<sub>i</sub> ⨯ ... ⨯ K<sub>i</sub> will not satisfy c<sub>i</sub> since all the literals in c<sub>i</sub> will be negated.

Consider the tuples (a, b, ..., k) ∈ S<sub>1</sub> ⋃ S<sub>2</sub> ⋃ ... ⋃ S<sub>n</sub>. These tuples belong to at least one S<sub>i</sub> so they will not satisfy c<sub>i</sub> and therefore fail to satisfy f.

If S<sub>1</sub> ⋃ S<sub>2</sub> ⋃ ... ⋃ S<sub>n</sub> is equal to S = A ⨯ B ⨯ ... ⨯ K, all the tuples fail to satisfy f and so f is unsatisfiable. It can be similarly shown that if the union is not equal to S there exists a tuple which satisfies f.

So 3SAT can be reduced to the complement of the original problem. But the complement of the original problem is in NP, because testing if a given tuple is not in the union can be done in polynomial time. So the complement of the original problem is NP-Complete, and the original problem itself is coNP-Complete.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible to do this efficiently. However, by checking progressively larger sets of sets, it would be possible in practice to bail out early if the answer is no:

- The union of `A1, ..., An` should be `A` for each set
- The union of `A1 x B1, ..., An x Bn` should be `A x B` for each pair of sets `A x B`
- Repeat for triples, etc. of sets

Thinking more about it, it seems unlikely to me that this can be checked fully without checking every element of `S`. Consider the following instance:

```
A = {a1, a2, a3}  B = {b1, b2, b3}  C = {c1, c2, c3}

A1 = A         B1 = B         C1 = {c2, c3}
A2 = A         B2 = {b2, b3}  C2 = C
A3 = {a2, a3}  B3 = B         C3 = C
```

Here the union of all `Sn` is `S - (a1, b1, c1)`. This seems hard to detect from the given subsets without explicitely checking for `(a1, b1, c1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The `S - (a1, b1, c1)` is indeed tricky. If there is an algorithm to do this, I imagine it would have to split the `Sn` into simpler, more combinable, terms.